# what does plus signature mean in makefile

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel

what does "+" mean in makefile ?

i found "+$(call if_changed,link-vmlinux)" in kernel makefile.

it means invoke make call function. But what's the "+" usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The + symbol means to execute the command under make -n

See the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))

> a plus sign (+), the command is executed even if Make is invoked in a
>   "do not execute" mode